# AngularJS and input type = date, how to format model data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, date, input

I have following form input which I'm trying to fill by scope data:

```
<input type="date" name="editCallForm.date"  ng-model="editCallForm.date">
```

I tried a few combination of date formatting, for example:

```
moment($rootScope.formData.date).format('DD/mm/YYYY');
```

But without luck (for time input is it working without problems).

What is the right format for this type of input?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

dates should be javascript date objects [reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D)
this says

```
The model must always be a Date object,
```

so

your codes should be

```
<input type="date" name="editCallForm.date"  ng-model="editCallForm.date">
```

and

```
$scope.editCallForm.date = new Date(); // set to today
```

if you want to format this date you can follow the Ben's answer , for Ex:

```
$scope.formattedDate = $filter('date')($scope.dateObj, "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

don't forget to add the `$filter` dependency in your controller

here is a [Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EcPX2tCyNSKDTvxaj1JJ?p=preview) please check

**note that** this feature is not works in older angular versions. its working angular 1.3 and onward

please check the breaking changes in angularjs change log [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#130-rc4-unicorn-hydrafication-2014-10-01)

---

If you need to do this in older versions of angularjs you can use something like [angular-ui bootstrap datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker)

here is the [Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9x4e03dFtd1NJPqgWp03?p=preview)